# How to add a sidebar to WordPress menus

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I need to get a widget inside a menu and I'm trying:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_widget_to_menu', 10, 2);
function add_widget_to_menu($items, $args) {
    if ($args->theme_location == 'mobile_menu')
        return $items .
               '<div id="newsletter-mobile">' .
               dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-mobile'        ) .
               '</div>';

    return $items;
}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sidebar using the following

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'name'=>'Widget_Name',
    'id'=>'widget_id',
    'before_widget' =>'<div class="">',
    'after_widget' =>'</div>'
));
```

To call this in your template, you can use the following code:

```
if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('widget_id')) :
endif;
```

Refer [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar) for more details.

Comment: Something seems to be missing from the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

This hook is used to add a sidebar menu in WordPress:

```
add_action("admin_menu", "sidebar_menu_for_registration");
```

sidebar_menu_for_registration is a function.

This is the syntax to create a sidebar menu:

```
add_menu_page(string $page_title, string $menu_title, string $capability, string $menu_slug, callable $function = '', string $icon_url = '', int $position = null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get 1 as output adding widget area to menu like that. The reason is that wp_nav_menu echoes the items. To make it work you should convert the contents of the widget area to string. I managed to solve the problem using buffering. Here is a small code sample that works for me:

```
function add_extra_item_to_nav_menu( $items, $args ) {
    ob_start();
        dynamic_sidebar( 'header-widget-area' );
    $menu_widget_area = ob_get_clean();
    $items .= $menu_widget_area;
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_extra_item_to_nav_menu', 10, 2 );
```